# Lookup to get data to populate based on a value from a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to the value in column D to do a lookup of column A from the second sheet and pull back the list of people in sheet 2 and put the list of people at the end of each profile_id in sheet 1. First two photos are the are of sheet 1 and 2. The last photo is of what I need the formula to create.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are adding rows in Sheet1, this means you will need VBA to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider manually copying and pasting a new row with formulas below each grouping of data (I'm assuming your rows are grouped by `corporate_profile_id` already), you can use the formula below to do the lookup based on the previous row.

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("D" & ROW() - 1), Sheet2!$A$2:$F$100, COLUMN(), FALSE)
```

**Warning:  please adjust `$F$100` accordingly before copying and pasting.**

What I would do is copy the formula above into the columns A9, B9, C9, D9, E9, and F9.  Then I would copy row 9 and paste it below each grouping of `corporate_profile_id` rows to get your final output (i.e. copy to your final rows 9, 16, 21, etc.).  I don't mind pasting an entire row without changes because it's usually quite fast.

Hope this works for you.

---

Here is a detailed explanation of the function, which does a lookup using the `corporate_profile_id` from the previous row.

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("D" & ROW() - 1), Sheet2!$A$2:$F$100, COLUMN(), FALSE)
```

The function parameters:

- Parameter 1 `INDIRECT("D" & ROW() - 1)` is the value to lookup:

  - `"D"` is the column
  - `ROW() - 1` is the previous row
  - The `INDIRECT` function returns the value in the column `"D" & ROW() - 1`.  If this formula was in row 9, then the function would become `INDIRECT("D8")` and return a value of **1**.
- Parameter 2 `Sheet2!$A$2:$F$100` is the lookup table range `$A$2:$F$100` on `Sheet2`.  The `$` prevents the row and column references from shifting when copying and pasting.  **Please adjust `$F$100` accordingly to cover your entire lookup table on `Sheet2`**.
- Parameter 3 `COLUMN()` is the column from your lookup table that you want to retrieve the value from.  `COLUMN()` itself returns the column number your formula is in (e.g. column **A** returns a value of **1**, column **B** returns a value of **2**, etc.).  Since the column of each formula lines up exactly with the return value column of the lookup table, it will return the correct value.  So column **A** would return the value in `profile_id`, column **B** would return the value in `profile_nme`, and so on to column **F** which returns the value in `employee_user_id`.
- Parameter 4 `FALSE` tells the `VLOOKUP` function to only match on an exact match.

Comment: The formula works really well in my example I forgot to show a corporate profile with multiple approvers. How would I change the formula to include corporate profiles with multiple people added?

517 Manufacturing Corporate (null) (null) Y ML47977
517 Manufacturing Corporate (null) (null) Y JS67769
517 Manufacturing Corporate (null) (null) Y ES86132
517 Manufacturing Corporate (null) (null) Y AS10456
517 Manufacturing Corporate (null) (null) Y MA37980

Comment: Unfortunately, VLOOKUP only works for returning one matching record.